# Can an enterprise app detect the presence of a Configuration Profile?

Tags: ios, ios5

I am developing an enterprise iPad app on iOS 5 that will store sensitive data on the device.  I intend to use iOS Data Protection to protect this data and need to enforce password complexity so that the encryption key used by DP is difficult to crack.  I plan on enforcing password complexity via a Configuration Profile that will be eventually distributed via MDM, but for now via the iPhone Configuration Utility.

So the goal is to insure that this Profile is present (and thus a complex password is configured) whenever the app runs.  Is there a way to "link" this enterprise app with this Profile?  I haven't found a way for an app to ask iOS what Profiles are installed (nor do I think there should be a way).  So what other options are there to accomplish this?

Comment: Well, when you start using MDM, you can require the profile which would mean that the only way to remove it is to un-enroll the device.  You can then specify (via MDM) that if the device is un-enrolled that your app (that was also installed via MDM) will be automatically uninstalled.  Until then I can't think of a way, but maybe someone else will have an idea....